# How to dynamically change the name of a dictionary based on a function argument?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically I am trying to make a simple quiz app and instead of writing out each of the individual questions, I am trying to speed it up by writing a function which will then create it for me.

This is what I have so far

```
func answerTemplate(answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, factNumber:String) {
    let fact("\(factNumber)") = ["A": "\(answerOne)", "B": "\(answerTwo)", "C": "\(answerThree)", "D": "\(answerFour)" ]
}
```

As you can see I am trying to change the dictionary name to be fact + the number of the question however this is giving me an error "consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by a ;).

Is there anyway to have it so that every time I create the function it will create a dictionary with a dynamic name?

here is how I am trying to create them:

```
let answerArray = [

    answerTemplate("Beach", "Crickets", "Pac-Man", "Banging", "one"),
    answerTemplate("Zipper", "Tie", "Shoe Lace", "Belt", "two"),
    answerTemplate("New York", "North Carolina", "Massachusetts", "Rhode Island", "three")
]
```

If  not, is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `let fact("\(factNumber)")`?

Comment: @wumm so say for example I put in "four" into the func arguments when I call it, that dictionary name will be "FactFour".

Comment: But why do you believe that should work? `let` declares a variable but what you are doing looks more like a function call. Or am I missing something? Where do you declare `fact`?

Comment: @wumm I want to make it so that every time I call this function, it creates a new variable called Fact(factNumber)

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare any variables at runtime in Swift. (What you are trying to do.)

Why would you want to do that?

Maybe you instead want to this:

```
var facts = [String:[String:String]]();

func answerTemplate(answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, factNumber:String) {
    facts[factNumber] = ["A": "\(answerOne)", "B": "\(answerTwo)", "C": "\(answerThree)", "D": "\(answerFour)" ]
}
```

I also don't understand why you are calling the function from an array:

```
let answerArray = [

    answerTemplate("Beach", "Crickets", "Pac-Man", "Banging", "one"),
    answerTemplate("Zipper", "Tie", "Shoe Lace", "Belt", "two"),
    answerTemplate("New York", "North Carolina", "Massachusetts", "Rhode Island", "three")
]
```

That makes no sense if you are pushing the contents into a directory anyway.